# Rails throwing a missing template error without having changed anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I've had my production rails app live for a couple months now with no issues. I haven't made any major changes recently (and not for a couple days) and then this morning, airbrake is throwing a bunch of errors for a specific callback that I have saying:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template calls/receive_call, application/receive_call
```

I haven't changed anything in the view or routes recently, what could be causing this? Here's my receive call method:

```
  def receive_call
    to_number   = params[:To]   == '+1' ? params[:Called].slice!(2..12) : params[:To].slice!(2..12)
    from_number = params[:From] == '+1' ? params[:Caller].slice!(2..12) : params[:From].slice!(2..12)
    company = PhoneNumber.find_by(number: to_number).company
    customer = company.customers.find_or_create_by(customer_phone_number: from_number)
    if company && customer
      call = company.calls.create(
        from:         from_number,
        to:           to_number,
        customer_id:  customer.id,
        call_status:  params[:CallStatus],
        call_sid:     params[:CallSid],
        forwarded_to: company.forwarding_number
      )
      forwarding_number = company.twilio_formatted_forwarding_number
      if forwarding_number
        render 'twilio/call_response.xml.haml', locals: { forwarding_number: forwarding_number }, content_type: 'text/xml'
      end
    else
      puts 'ERROR (receive_call): company or customer couldn\'t be loaded'
    end
  end
```

I've never needed a view for this callback (from twilio) before...but now it's saying I need one. What's going on?

Comment: Here's a guess: for whatever reason, your `if company && customer` statement is returning false causing you to `puts` the error but not call `render`. Perhaps try calling `render nothing: true, status: 422` after the `puts`.

Comment: @jsksma2 but why has this code worked for 2 months and randomly stopped working completely this morning?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you look into your method, for the first if statement if there is no forwarding_number then your second if statement doesn't get execute and there's no else block either so rails must be looking for its corresponding view

Comment: Like I said, my guess is that your if statement suddenly started returning false. Perhaps your PhoneNumber table is returning a `nil` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, it's the first time you have an error.
If the error occurs, you output the error with puts.
At the end of the action, Rails tries to render the standard view, because nothing was rendered yet.

You can render the pure text as

```
      if forwarding_number
        render 'twilio/call_response.xml.haml', locals: { forwarding_number: forwarding_number }, content_type: 'text/xml'
      else
        render text: 'ERROR (receive_call): no forwarding number.'
      end
    else
      render text: 'ERROR (receive_call): company or customer couldn\'t be loaded'
    end
```

or return after the `puts`:

```
puts 'ERROR (receive_call): company or customer couldn\'t be loaded'
return
```

Of cause, you should render the same type of response (XML) whether there is an error or not, so better do

```
render xml: {error: 'ERROR (receive_call): company or customer couldn\'t be loaded'}, status: 404
```

etc.

Comment: it seems by just creating a blank receive_call.html.haml file...it works now...so weird...not sure what changed

Comment: of cause, then there is *something* to render when the actions ends without any explicit render.